# Show full layer name (including extension) in QGIS table of contents

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, table-of-contents

Is there an option in QGIS to show the full name of a layer (including the extension) in the TOC?

I'll take a python solution as well, but it would need to trigger on layers being added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there's a QGIS option for that, but you can accomplish it with the following code snippet:

```py
import os.path

def showFullName( addedLayers ):
  for layer in addedLayers:
    source = layer.source()
    if os.path.isfile( source ): 
      layer.setLayerName( os.path.basename( source ) )

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().layersAdded.connect( showFullName )
```

---

*Note: There are cases where the code above won't show the extension for file-based layers. For instance, delimited text layers or sublayers from a GPX file. You'd need to tweak the code above to work also in those cases.*

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks.  Note for those who come after - this code doesn't rename items already in the TOC but monitors for added layers and then displays the full name of layers who subsequently add.

Comment: +1, I was aware of the `layersAdded` signal but wasn't sure how to correctly use it (didn't realise you needed a `for` loop). This solves a number of issues I previously had :)